# Select rows where specific column value is close to another?

Tags: mysql, group-by, range

I have a list of orders, packages, and their weights. I want to select all orders that have packages that are close in weight.

```
|Order|Package|Weight|
|1111 | 1212  |  1.20|
|1111 | 1213  |  1.28|
|1111 | 1214  |  2.56|
|1333 | 1455  | 10.20|
|1333 | 1459  | 10.31|
```

This select would be used to return package 1212, 1213 for order 1111 and package 1455 and 1459 for order 1333.

The point isn't to be within a specific range of weights, it's that one package on the order is within a specific range of another.

For example (pseudo):

```
SELECT Package FROM PackagesTable WHERE Weight within 0.25 GROUP BY Order
```

Comment: How do you decide on the range? What is considered "close"?

Comment: @Mureinik Added a pseudo-code example of that.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the requirements. Suppose you have `1`, `1.2` and `1.4`.  1 and 1.2 are within 0.25 of each other, as are 1.2 and 1.4, but 1 and 1.4 are not. Would you have them all in a single group? Two groups? And if so, where would you put 1.2?

Comment: I would return all of them, because 0.25 in this case is the criteria for similar weight.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Order BETWEEN lowerbound AND upperbound;
```

Values for lowerbound and upperbound would be your range.